# How to create a size element in Stripe checkout Page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am currently using the Stripe API, I read that is possible to create a size dropdown element with "Large, "Medium" and "Small" options inside the stripe checkout page so that the customer can choose the size of an item and pass it on as the description to stripe so that I can know in my end which size they selected. I'm new to node.js and I'm having a hard time implementing this functionality to the checkout page. Here is my current backend code which only displays the "provide shipping info" element as well as the "provide card info" element inside my Stripe Checkout page:

```
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
STRIPE_KEY
);

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
const items = req.body.items;

let lineItems = [];
items.forEach((item) => {
lineItems.push({
  price: item.id,
  quantity: item.quantity,
});
});


const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
line_items: lineItems,
mode: "payment",
billing_address_collection: "required",
shipping_address_collection: {
  allowed_countries: ["US", "CA"],
},
shipping_options: [
  {
    shipping_rate_data: {
      type: "fixed_amount",
      fixed_amount: { amount: 0, currency: "usd" },
      display_name: "Free shipping",
      delivery_estimate: {
        minimum: { unit: "business_day", value: 5 },
        maximum: { unit: "business_day", value: 7 },
      },
    },
  },
],
success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/cancel",
});

res.send(
JSON.stringify({
  url: session.url,
})
);
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Listening on port 4000!"));
```

I also tried having the size dropdown in my front end so that when the user would select a size they would be redirected to a page with the price ID as well as its price etc. Only problem I am using the Link component from react-router-dom to redirect user to correct page with the size they want and the onlclick method to change the dropdown toggle title to the size that they selected, so by doing this it seems to sometimes ignore the onlcick method and not change the dropdown toggle title to the selected size and instead favors the Link component to redirect user to page which never fail. Here is my code:

```
  const [sizeLabel, sizeLabelFunc] = React.useState("Select Size");

   <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle id="dropdown-basic">
              {sizeLabel}
            </Dropdown.Toggle>

            <Dropdown.Menu>
              <Dropdown.Item
                onClick={() =>
                  sizeLabelFunc("Large (1-inch Width 18-26-inch Length)")
                }
              >
                <Link to={"http://localhost:3000/Pag1Large"}>
                  Large (1-inch Width 18-26-inch Length)
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
              <Dropdown.Item
                onClick={() =>
                  sizeLabelFunc("Medium (1-inch Width 12-18-inch Length)")
                }
              >
                <Link to={"http://localhost:3000/Pag1Medium"}>
                  Medium (1-inch Width 12-18-inch Length)
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>

              <Dropdown.Item
                onClick={() =>
                  sizeLabelFunc("Small (5/8-inch Width 8-12-Length)")
                }
              >
                <Link to={"http://localhost:3000/Pag1Small"}>
                  Small (5/8-inch Width 8-12-Length)
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
       </Dropdown>
```

Any code example on either problem would be really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilise the [custom fields](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-fields) feature to configure Checkout to collect additional information from your customers during payment. Using your example above, you could adapt your session creation code to include the [`custom_fields` parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-custom_fields):

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  // Other required parameters
  custom_fields: [{
    key: 'size',
    label: {
      custom: 'Size',
      type: 'custom'
    },
    dropdown: {
      // Include up to 200 options as required
      options: [{
        label: 'Small',
        value: 'small'
      }]
    },
    type: 'dropdown'
  }]
})
```

Your customers will be required to select an option/complete the fields before paying, and submitted details will be present in the payload of the corresponding `checkout.session.completed` event.

Comment: Thank you so much! I looked all over the Stripe documentation for something like this.

Comment: It's a very new feature (just shipped this week).